# User can create in SSRS, but can't manage objects

Tags: security, permissions, ssrs, ssrs-2008-r2

We have a user who can create, but is unable to manage objects in SSRS, even though he has content manager permissions and another user who has same permissions who is able to.

It is SSRS 2008 R2, the folder is nested, but permissions have been broken for only specific users that differ from parent folder.  User 1 is on Win7 computer with IE11 and Chrome, doing run as admin and not - not sure why he's doing that, but I didn't instruct him either way.

We have two users that started with same permissions (Browser, Content Manager, My Reports, Publisher, Report Builder), but user 1 can only create objects and cannot manage them.  We tried the following to no avail:

- Remove all but content manager
- Remove a security group that only had Browser permission, in case he was nested in there and it was granting lowest permissions only
- Grant System User permissions in Site Settings
- Granted Content Manager at parent folder level
- Connecting through a different machine (RDP'd to a server)
- Granted System Administrator permissions in Site Settings
- Restarting user 1's computer
- Clearing cache has been done several times
- Trying from another user's Win7 computer

After System Administrator still didn't work, we asked user 2 to try, and it worked.  He only has Content Manager permissions.  That's where it got weird.  These users are both developers, and now user 1 has higher permissions than user 2, but he still can't change anything.  Yes, I confirmed the username is what he is using.

The error is:  The permissions granted to user 'domain\username' are insufficient for performing this operation

Has anyone experienced this or something similar, and can you share some wisdom?  After scouring the web, we're at a loss and our next step is to reach out to MS since this is to get us off a failing server.

Sorry if this has been raised before - I tried searching the site and only found one question that didn't match.